# ruby-on-rails - Problem with Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I have a Problem with Nested Resources.

**2 Models**

```
User => has_many :stuffs

Stuff => belongs_to :user
```

**routes.rb**

```
map.resources :stuffs

map.resources :users, :has_many => [:stuffs]
```

When i call /users/1/stuffs it presents me the Stuff for the corresponding User. but i got this also when i call /users/2/stuffs. It should return 0 "Stuffs" but it dont work.

```
MySQL Query from Server
SELECT * FROM `stuffs`
```

rake routes

```
stuffs GET    /stuffs(.:format)                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"stuffs"}
                POST   /stuffs(.:format)                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"stuffs"}
      new_stuff GET    /stuffs/new(.:format)                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"stuffs"}
     edit_stuff GET    /stuffs/:id/edit(.:format)                {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"stuffs"}
          stuff GET    /stuffs/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stuffs"}
                PUT    /stuffs/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"stuffs"}
                DELETE /stuffs/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"stuffs"}
    user_stuffs GET    /users/:user_id/stuffs(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"stuffs"}
                POST   /users/:user_id/stuffs(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"stuffs"}
 new_user_stuff GET    /users/:user_id/stuffs/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"stuffs"}
edit_user_stuff GET    /users/:user_id/stuffs/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"stuffs"}
     user_stuff GET    /users/:user_id/stuffs/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stuffs"}
                PUT    /users/:user_id/stuffs/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"stuffs"}
                DELETE /users/:user_id/stuffs/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"stuffs"}
          users GET    /users(.:format)                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                POST   /users(.:format)                          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                 {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
           root        /                                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
```

gem list

```
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
arel (2.0.6)
authlogic (2.1.6)
builder (2.1.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.5.0)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
paperclip (2.3.7)
rack (1.1.0)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
```

There is no where clause for the corresponding user_id. But how to fix it?

Rails Version 2.3.8

#### Should work like this => http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html 2.7 Nested Resources

Hope somebody can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Stuffs controller's index method, how are you collecting your stuffs? If you used a scaffold to create the controller it will default to something like

```
@stuffs = Stuff.all
```

but should be something along the lines of

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@stuffs = @user.stuffs
```

or something to that effect--basically, you're collecting the user's stuff, not all stuff.

Comment: Hm, i could do that, but i thought rails takes this part, when i add the :has_many relationship in routes.rb. I Also want to call /stuffs/ With your Code it will throw an error :(

Comment: If you want to list all Stuff on /stuffs/ and a user's Stuff on /user/:user_id/stuffs, you'll have to check for the user_id parameter. Essentially, if params[:user_id] is set, use the code that gets the user's stuff, otherwise get everything.

Comment: I thought rails autmaticlly handles that. Like here => http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

Comment: @Nihil if you follow the link to the full source code you can see where he loads the filtered collection:   https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-139/blog/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

Answer (score 3):

Rails controllers will not filter your results by default. As above, since you're probably calling Stuff.all in your StuffsController, it will always return all Stuff objects.

I use inherited_resources for the default behaviour on my sites. It handles these relationships automatically and lets you override it when you want different behaviour:

https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

Answer (score 0):

Routes alone don't affect the model.  Since the user id is passed in, though, you can do:

```
User.find(params[:user_id]).stuffs
```

Comment: Hm, but it should work, thats the problem :( See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html 2.7 Nested Resources

Comment: No, that only affects the url routing. When you get the collection of objects, you still have to filter it by the nested id yourself.  That guide makes no claim otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
map.resources :users do |users|
  users.resources :stuffs
end
```

Comment: Dont work :( Same Problem with the :has_many option in routes.rb

Comment: so there is problem in controller... check the above answers